# C++ understand reference in default parameter

Tags: c++, reference

I have a question about reference in default parameter in C++.

Exemple : `SWindows(const std::string&, int, const std::string& flag = "UDP");`

I don't understand why this code compile (IDE Visual studio 2012).
For me, a reference it's an object alias. So We can't declared this line. It's supposed that the "flag" already exists.

So it's a compiler optimization or a misunderstanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the code

```
SWindows(const std::string&, int, const std::string& flag = "UDP");
```

you should split it into two parts.

```
SWindows(const std::string&, int, const std::string& flag );

SWindows( SomeString, SomeInt, "UDP" );
```

As "UDP" is not of type std::string then it implicitly is converted to an object of type std::string by calling the constructor that accepts a string literal as its first argument. So the last statement is equivalent to

```
SWindows( SomeString, SomeInt, std::string( "UDP" ) );
```

The result of expression std::string( "UDP ) is a temporary object that you may bind to a const reference. So the const reference is an alias of that temporary object,

You can imagine this such a way that inside the body of the function there is definition

```
const std::string &flag = std::string( "UDP" );
```

Answer (score 3):

A `const` lvalue can bind to a temporary object. That's all. So, that code is legal and well formed.

The lifetime of that temporary object will be extended as long as `flag` exists.
It doesn't need to say, you can not bind a temporary object to a non-const lvalue reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with const references. You can also use rvalues with const references like:

```
void SomeFunction(SomeObject const& s)
 { ... };
```

And then you can call

```
SomeFunction(SomeObject());
```

You can do this because by saying its a const reference, you are telling you won't be modifying the referenced variable. If it wasn't a `const&` you wouldn't be able to do that.